# Wrap an element for each set of elements with SimpleXML/DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml

I have the code below to create a XML file

```
<?php
 try
{
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "items" ));
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );

    $sxe->addChild("model", "HTC Desire");
    $sxe->addChild("model", "Motorola Atrix");
    echo $sxe->asXML();
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

While execute this code, it will generate the content likes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
<model>HTC Desire</model>
<model>Motorola Atrix</model>
</items>
```

But, I would like to wrap an element called `item` for each model, the result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
<item><model>HTC Desire</model></item>
<item><model>Motorola Atrix</model></item>
</items>
```

Anyone could suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addChild method returns a SimpleXMLElement object representing the child added to the XML node. This allows for method chaining like so:

```
try
{
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "items" ));
    $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $sxe->addChild("item")->addChild("model", "HTC Desire");
    $sxe->addChild("item")->addChild("model", "Motorola Atrix");

    echo $sxe->asXML();
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but I got `<item />` before. Dunno what happen. Anyway your suggestion works, thanks